# I am trying to display PDF file from SQL Server using ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web-deployment-project

When I click on download link, then the error shown occurs - please help me. Thank you.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="newsfile" HeaderText="newsfile" SortExpression="newsfile" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="details" HeaderText="details" SortExpression="details" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentFile" HeaderText="DocumentFile" SortExpression="DocumentFile" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Admin_FK" HeaderText="Admin_FK" SortExpression="Admin_FK" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="newsfile" DataTextField="newsfile" HeaderText="newsfile" Text="newsfile" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WSSBConnectionString4 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tender2]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This error occurs:

[image: This is the error]

Comment: i save my file as a varchar(MAX) in sql server.

Comment: where is the download code ?

Comment: And where's the "download link" you click on ? You need to **SHOW US** the relevant parts! We can't see your screen, your code, nor can we read your mind .....

Comment: my error problem was that the file not save in folder in solution explorer. now I correct this problem thank you every one .